# Increment variable in constructor function (JS)

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am fetching the data from 2 different APIs and I wrote a constructor function that will start XMLHttpRequest based on the new instance of the object creation (if it makes any sense...). Once the data is fetched and parsed I want to save it into different named variables. For instance: trial1data, trial2data. At the minute the new instances of the objects overwrite the data variable. Code below:

```
var api = "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&pretty=true";
var api2 = "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&tel={phone|format}&address={streetAddress}&city={city}&state={usState|abbr}&zip={zip}&pretty=true";

function FetchData(apiType) {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.apiType = apiType;
    this.request = function() {
        r.open("GET", apiType, true);
        r.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        }
        r.send(null);
    }
}

trial1 = new FetchData (api);
trial1.request();

trial2 = new FetchData (api2);
trial2.request();
```

Thanks for the XMLHttpRequest tip, but the issue was to save each data into separate variables such as trial1data and trial2data (or anything else that has got a meaning and I can re-use later on), based on how many new objects I will create.

Comment: You should check documentation and/or blog posts about how to write "classes" in Javascript. For example, it makes no sense to assign a function inside the constructor. I don't think you need a class anyway, given your example. Just use functions and, if you need it, lexical scope.

Comment: @Mörre classess are just a sugar and do not change anything and what he did is properly configured constructor for a ES5. He should move request method to prototype but it is not the case about how to makie it more fancier but why it does not work and the reason is shared instance of XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: "At the minute the new instances of the objects overwrite the data variable." How do you know this? How do you know that they are not separate variables with independent values?

Comment: It is not wrong. It is possible, and then the method will be replicated in all instances. It is doable and described in docs. It makes sense then. However arguing about "how to create method in js" in context of this question actually makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the XMLHttpRequest tip, but the issue I have is to save each data into separate variables such as trial1data and trial2data.

Comment: @BartoszHerba WTF? Your reply is more than strange. I would appreciate getting replies that have a connection to what I wrote and are not responses to "interpretations" of what you think you read you yourself invent in your own head. I really don't need a lesson in Javascript from you. Just for starters, you realize I wrote _"classes"_ - with quotes? As I already said, OP needs to read up on the very basics of the language. According to what most users here say SO is NOT a site to teach the language basics.

Comment: @BartoszHerba Thank you for your unmasking reply - I'm glad everybody can see you clearly now! Insults - the last resort of people without arguments. Ironically your comment applies to yourself first of all, in a form of self-fulfilling prophecy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create new instance on var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); inside of constructor, or as a better approach, make it an argument for a constructor and inject new XMLHttpRequets object for each.

To answer the second part of your question, you could store response data in object's property and access it directly or getter interface. So instead of

```
 r.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
 }
```

Do something like:

```
function FetchData(apiType) {

  var self = this;
  this.apiType = apiType;
  this.request = function() {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      r.open("GET", apiType, true);
      r.onload = function() {
        self.data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        resolve(self.data);
      }
      r.send(null);
    }   
}
```

Then

```
trial1 = new FetchData (api);
var trial1resp;
trial1.request().then(function(data) {
   trial1resp = data;
}
```

The last assignment is just to show how is response stored. You must handle async processess to achieve your goal.

You could read little bit more about promisses and how to handle xhr async tasks here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Answer (score 1):

Your `var r = new XMLHttpRequest();` is common.

You need to move it inside the function to create separate request everytime the constructor function is called.

```
function FetchData(apiType) {

    this.apiType = apiType;
    this.request = function() {

        var r = new XMLHttpRequest();

        r.open("GET", apiType, true);
        r.onload = function() {
           var data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
           console.log(data);
        }
        r.send(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the request object creation inside the constructor:

```
function FetchData(apiType) {
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  this.apiType = apiType;

  this.done = new Promise( res => {
    r.onload = function() {
      res(JSON.parse(r.responseText) );          
    };
  });
  this.request = function() {
    r.open("GET", apiType, true);
    r.send(null);
  }; 
}
```

So you can do:

```
const req = new FetchData("whatever");
req.request();
req.done.then(console.log);
```